# Rewriting Multiple JOINS as SUBQUERIES

Tags: sql

I need to find the names of all my salespeople that represent a paticular band in my Artists Table.

My Tables resmeble the following:

### Salespeople

SalesID, Firstname, Lastname

### Artists

ArtistID, ArtistName

### Members

MembersID, Firstname, Lastname. SalesID

The MembersID and Artists tables are related by the following table:

### xRefArtistsMembers

ArtistID, MemberID

I formulated the following query:

```
 select sp.firstname, sp.lastname from salespeople sp
 inner join members m on (m.salesid = sp.salesid)
 inner join xrefartistsmembers x on (x.memberid = m.memberid)
 inner join artists a where a.artistname = "The Bullets";
```

Is their also a way to do this with subqueries?

Comment: if you receive an "empty set" that means your query is fine (at least syntactically), there's just nothing in your db that matches your request. Idk if i would personally set up my tables this way but your query seems to be appropriate for what you are trying to achieve. Are you positive there are sales ppl related "The Bullets" that SHOULD get returned?

Comment: From experienced eyes, do you see anything immediately wrong w/my query? It is strange, I data for this exists!

Comment: The query looks right. There might be a data issue. I would recommend running it in stages. Run just the first line. then run the first two lines to see if you are getting anything. etc...

If you are still having trouble, post some example rows and what result you are expecting.

Comment: I guess my question is just how to rewrite it as subquery?

Comment: There is no reason that I know of to rewrite this as a subquery. Joins are usually going to be faster.

Comment: your query looks fine, I would follow @dagarrison and IanDavis's suggestions...

Comment: Note: your `inner join artists a where a.artistname = "The Bullets";` is effectively a carthesian product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sp.firstname, sp.lastname from salespeople sp
inner join members m on (m.salesid = sp.salesid)
inner join xrefartistsmembers x on (x.memberid = m.memberid)
inner join artists a on a.artistID = x.artistID
where a.artistname = "The Bullets"
```

Comment: How would you write that as a subquery?

Comment: I am not understanding why you want to use a subquery, or for which part you want to use a subquery. This is very clearly a job for joins.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't your inner join to artists have an `on` clause then your `where` clause?

```
inner join artists a where a.artistname = "The Bullets";
```

would be

```
inner join artists a on a.artistid = x.artistid
where artists.artistname = "The Bullets";
```

Comment: That produces the same result.

Comment: The first one reads as a Join that automatically matches up the Ids based on name and then filters out all but "The Bullets". The second just explicitely specifies the join condition. These should produce the same thing in this case.

Comment: @dagarrison "reads as a Join that automatically matches up the Ids based on name" - learned something new today, thanks

Comment: A lot of sql syntaxes won't actually let you do this and requires the join condition to be specified.. The context isn't really specified in the question though.